# class attribute in Razor

Tags: razor

I am building a MVC4 app (my first) and using Razor for the first time as well.
I am currently building a simple site and using MVCSitemapProvider for the Menu and Breadcrumb stuff.

In my menu i need to output some css class depending on if the current item is active and a custom class i added to the mvc.sitemap.

This is what i have;

```
<li class="
@if (node.IsCurrentNode){<text>active </text>}
@if (node.Children.Any()){<text>has-sub</text>}
">
```

The above works as expected - but it does not look nice in a view source for instance.
The class attribute is always shown - even if it is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Conditional Attributes in Web Pages 2](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/201/Cleaner-Conditional-HTML-Attributes-In-Razor-Web-Pages) (MVC 4) to cause the class attribute and its value to render only if the expression you pass in does not result in `null`:

```
<li class="@(node.IsCurrentNode ? "active" : null)">
```

Comment: Perfect, thx! I knew i had seen that somewhere in my MVC4 training :)